# Use AngularJS expressions in Javascript controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there some way to evaluate [AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) in the context of a controller, service, or directive, [like a filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives)?

I rather like the fact that expressions are very elegant when mashing data, especially deeply nested objects with optional keys.

Something like:

`$expression("[foo.bar.bar, foo.bar.baz, foo.bar] | lowercase", object);`

Comment: AngularJS expression is functional code, it is not a statement.

Comment: @Husky: Did you take a look at my answer ? Did it solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter in JS with the **[`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24filter)** service:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($filter, $scope) {
    $scope.lower = $filter('lowercase')('HELLO, WORLD !');
    // -> $scope.lower will be 'hello, world !'
});
```

If you don't want to use a filter, but evaluate an expression (although I can't think of any good reason), you can use `$scope.$eval()`:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.someProp = 'HELLO, WORLD !';
    $scope.lower = $scope.$eval('someProp | lowercase');
    // -> $scope.lower will be 'hello, world !'
});
```

Comment: Yes, i know that. But how do i use an expression?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. See my updated answer. Is that what you mean ? Basically, anything that could appear inside `{{ }}` in the view, can be passed to `$eval()` (omitting the `{{` `}}`).

Comment: Maybe he means something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/pJlFz4973sDUmhuF7WtY?p=preview

Comment: @tasseKATT: Yes, I think it's actually the same thing as my second code-block. Any expression that would be evaluated in the view, can be also evaluated in the controller (although I still don't see any reason why one would want something like this).

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing. Just tried to clarify for the OP that is it :)

Comment: @Husky: Did you take a look at my updated answer ? Does it work for you ?

Comment: I use $scope.$eval to get values using the expression syntax because it avoids lots of isDefined/!= null testing..

Comment: Thanks! `$scope.$eval` was indeed exactly what i was looking for. Like @ScottWarren said, it's a more elegant and easier syntax than just using raw JS.